# Why is the image being removed from the cache? | Kingfisher

Tags: swiftui, kingfisher

I am using Kingfisher on SwiftUI. I download the image from `url` with Kingfisher

**I will explain the problem step by step:**

1. I download the image from url
2. After I close my own application from the background, I open the Instagram application and scroll down continuously on the main page and I make the Instagram application use the cache.
3. Then I turn off the internet and open my own application.

**Problem:** When I turn off my internet and open my own application again, I cannot get the pictures from the cache. Why ?

`.diskCacheAccessExtending(.expirationTime(.never))` and `.diskCacheExpiration(.never)` I used these two functions, but the images are still deleted from the cache.

**KFImage:**

```
KFImage.url(URL(string: value))
    .resizing(referenceSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50), mode: .aspectFit)
    .diskCacheExpiration(.never) // 1
    .diskCacheAccessExtending(.expirationTime(.never)) // 2
                              .loadDiskFileSynchronously()
                              .fade(duration: 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In KF the cache is being saved in the Cache directory which is not permanent and might be deleted by the system